# Calling a function from inside another function-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a class where I have some querying being done in the `__init__` function. This sort of querying is needed in a lot of steps and that is why I have a generic `Query_Execution` function. I am having trouble calling it. I have another function `function 2` that does some calculation and creates a list. I want to call the `Query_Execution` function there. How do I do this?

```
class Something:

def __init__(self, master):

    self.top_frame = Frame(master, bg = 'green')
    self.top_frame.pack(fill = BOTH)
    self.middle_frame = Frame(master, bg = 'blue')
    self.middle_frame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH)
    self.bottom_frame = Frame(master, bg = 'red')
    self.bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill = BOTH)

    # A generic function to create lists
    def Query_Execution(execution_string, selection_parameter):
        cursor.execute(execution_string)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        result_list = [selection_parameter, 'All']
        for result in results:
            result_list.append(result[0])
        return result_list

    #The list of things in the first drop down
    execution_string = 'SELECT DISTINCT item_list FROM some db;'
    selection_paramter = 'item list'
    self.business_unit_list = Query_Execution(execution_string, selection_paramter)


    #This creates the drop down
    *The code to create Drop Down-Option Menu from tkinter*

    #The list of things in the States drop down
    execution_string = 'SELECT DISTINCT item_2 FROM some_db0;'
    selection_paramter = 'item 2'
    self.state_list = Query_Execution(execution_string, selection_paramter)

    #This creates the drop down
    *Code for creating drop down*


#Some Other function
def fucntion2(self, value):
    execution_string = 'SELECT DISTINCT item_3 FROM soem db WHERE item_1 = \'%s\' ;' %(self.var_business_unit.get())
    selection_parameter = 'Product Category'
    self.product_category_list = self.Query_Execution(execution_string, selection_parameter)    

*Here I want to call the Query_Execution function*
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Don't define `Query_Execution` inside `__init__` make it available everywhere in the class by defining it as another method.

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't be performing database access in a class constructor

Comment: That will work and then I can do `self.Query_Execution` and have `Query_Execution(self,....)`

Comment: I want that code to run as soon as you create an object and the class constructor helps with that. What sort of problems will I come across if I do it there? @UnholySheep

Comment: 1. Constructing an object becomes slow (because database access is slow) 2. Construction can fail (e.g.: if the connection to the database fails)

Comment: also I would follow python naming standards and calling it `query_execution` not `Query_Execution`.